# couldn't get json from url

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to get json from a url but did not succeed..

here is my code. i am trying using jsonParse method.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php getBaseURL(); ?>style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!--<div id="menu"></div>-->
            <!--<img class="img-responsive" src="http://f1.haveeru.com.mv/photos/2014/08/0_14082524222_news.jpg" />
        <img src="http://f1.haveeru.com.mv/dhivehi/images/haveeru_logo_m.jpg" />-->
        <div id="demo"></div>
    </div>
    <script language="javascript">

        var url = "http://api.haveeru.com.mv/articles/read/160917";

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                myFunction(myArr);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        function myFunction(arr) {
            var out = "";

            out += arr.heading;
            }
            alert(out);
        }


</script>
</body>
```

it is not even alerting anything..

any help would be appriciated.. thank you

Comment: Use console log rather than alerts, that can save some time.

Comment: There is an extra closing bracket `}` on `myFunction`

Comment: Origin issue? JSONP perhaps? Not to mention TWO jQuery libraries not used

Comment: hey guys.. i have solved the issue.. its a problem with cross domain.. thank you all for the support.. [check this link](http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/)

Answer (score 2):

there are multiple issues with your code

#### 1. Unwanted closing brase in `myFunction` defintion

See the defintion of `myFunction`, you can see an unwanted closing brace which need to be removed.

#### 2. xmlhttp object is not defined

you have declare the xmlhttp object with `new XMLHttpRequest();`. This would differ in IE older versions as you need `ActiveXObject` instead of this. Also you already have Jquery as dependency in the code. Then you could use `$.ajax` or `$.getJSON` instead of this code. Your code will become even more readable.

#### 3. cross domain origin issue

You have to resolve it either by providing Allow access control headers from the requested resource or by using jsonp if the service supports it. You can resolve this issue by

a. setting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' headers on the response sent by ajax target if you have the permission to do so.

b. use jsonp as an alternative if its supported by the target service

c. if none of the above works, you can make a local server side page which reads and forwards the response to you via a local route which your ajax call can consume.

Comment: In jsfidlle it also complaints about xmlhttp not being defined.

Comment: No need for xmlhttp when jQuery is loaded. Must be using JSONP though

Answer (score 0):

1.I can't see xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

2.closing bracket } in myfunction

Answer (score 0):

Better practice would be to use a function to create the `XMLHttpRequest`  or a `XDomainRequest` using this function :

```
function getXDomainRequest() {
    var xdr = null;

    if (window.XDomainRequest) {
        xdr = new XDomainRequest();
    } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xdr = new XMLHttpRequest({mozSystem: true});
    } else {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX");
    }
    return xdr;
}
```

Comment: Even better would be to do a $.ajax or $.getJSON